# When the tensor product of two module elements is nonzero

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, tensor-products

What are the main cases in which we can say that $a \otimes b \neq 0 \in A \otimes B$, where $A$ and $B$ are $R$ modules?

It works for nonzero elements in free modules over an integral domain.

**Additional Question:** What can we say about when all tensors are elementary? It is true when one of the factors is cyclic...is that the only reliable principle?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637175/

Comment: @Watson That's not really the kind of answer I'm going for. I'm looking for things like "if $A$ and $B$ are torsion free, and $R$ is a such-and-such ring..."

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary and sufficient there exists a bilinear map $A\times B\to M$ for some other module $M$ where $a\otimes b$ has nonzero image.

Comment: (And this a necessary and sufficient condition, in fact. Indeed, one can take M to be the tensor product of A and B and the map the canonical bilinear map)