# 0 element of tensor product of two abelian groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider tensor product of two abelian groups, $A\otimes B$. Then is there any if and only if condition for satisfying $ a\otimes b\;is\; 0 \iff\ a=0\;or\;b=0$?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but try https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637175/how-to-prove-an-element-is-non-zero-in-a-tensor-product